# Feature selection on subsets of feature set

Tags: r, classification, feature-selection

I am trying to do the feature selection using Boruta package in R. The problem is that my feature set is way tooo large (70518 features) and therefore the dataframe is too large (2Gb) and cannot be processed by the Boruta package at once. I am wondering if I can split the data frame into several sets, each containing a smaller amount of features? This sounds a bit weird to me, as I am not sure if the algorithm can correctly identify the weights if not all features are present. 
If not, I would be very grateful if someone can suggest an alternative way of doing it.

Comment: how many records you have?

Comment: I have 1157 instances and 70518 features. of which I am using 786 as a training set and 371 for testing

Comment: You could better take half of your instances and try again. I think you should keep all features together. However Keith is already suggesting the caret package. It should be possible to do feature selection with the size of dataframe you have. You could otherwise consider performing a univariate filter e.g.: variance filtering to do a feature pre-selection before you do the real feature selection. Just to reduce dimensionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best best in this case might be to first try and filter out some of the features that are either low information (e.g. ~zero variance) or highly correlated.

The [caret package](https://topepo.github.io/caret/) has [some useful functions to help with this](https://topepo.github.io/caret/pre-processing.html#corr).

For example, the `findCorrelation()` can be used to easily remove redundant features:

```
dat <- cor(dat, method='spearman')
dat[is.na(dat)] <- 0

features_to_ignore <- findCorrelation(dat, cutoff=0.75, verbose=FALSE)
dat <- dat[,-features_to_ignore]
```

This will remove all features with a Spearman correlation of 0.75 or higher.

Comment: thanks, but again, this does not work with a large dataset. will splitting it up affect anything?

Comment: Intuitively, splitting the data will not be entirely effective. For instance, if two highly correlated features end up in different partitions, they will not be excluded from the analysis.

Is the problem that the dataset is too large to hold in memory at once? Or is it specifically that the Boruta package runs out of memory?

Comment: It is too large to hold in memory at once. Sorry for being not clear

Comment: In that case, assuming you don't have access to a machine with more memory, you might consider randomly sub-sampling on the rows (using the `sample()` function), as much as is necessary to fit in memory. To be sure, you can repeat the process several times using different samples, and then take the intersection of variables filtered out across all (or some proportion of) the samples.

Comment: Alternatively, another approach that might work would be to iteratively filter the features. As I mentioned in my first comment above, the filtering will not be effective across a single partitioning because it can _miss_ correlated features and such, but assuming is able to filter out correlated / low-variance features within each partition, you could then recombine the filtered data sets and redo the feature selection. If necessary, you can repeat this many times to slowly work back up to the full combined data set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start by asking why you believe that this can even work? In this case, not only is `p >> n`, but `p >>>>>> n`. You're always going to find spurious associations. More than that, even if you could do this (say by renting a sufficiently large machine in a cloud computing service, which is the method I'd suggest), you're looking at an absurd amount of computation, since the computational complexity of building a single decision tree is `O(n * v log(v))`, where `n` is the number of records and `v` is the number for fields in each record. Building an RF takes that much for each tree.

Instead of solving the problem as stated, you might want to rethink it from the ground up.  What are you *really* trying to do here? Can you go back to first principles and rethink that?